# Need assistance with boolean logic

Tags: java, boolean

I'm taking an AP Computer Science Course at my High School, and for our practice quiz, I get all of the questions right except for this one. Can you explain it to me?

---

---

In the following statement, a and b are boolean variables:

```
boolean c = (a && b) || !(a || b);
```

Under what conditions with the value of c be true?

- A. Only when the value of a is different than the value of b.
- B. Only when the value of a is the same as the value of b.
- C. Only when a and b are both true.
- D. Only when a and b are both false.
- E. The value of c will be true for all values of a and b.

Comment: For each option, try plugging the truth values of `a` and `b` into the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to write code and enjoy doing truth tables as much as I do it would tell you the correct answer too:

```
a b    (a && b) ||  !(a || b)
0 0     0 0 0    1  1 0  0 0      <- this row
0 1     0 0 1    0  0 0  1 1
1 0     1 0 0    0  0 1  1 0
1 1     1 1 1    1  0 1  1 1      <- this row
```

So it's *B. Only when the value of a is the same as the value of b.*

This would look so much better if SO supported LaTeX commands...

Answer (score 2):

Let's find out,

```
boolean[] test = { true, false };
for (boolean a : test) {
    for (boolean b : test) {
        boolean c = (a && b) || !(a || b);
        System.out.printf("a=%s, b=%s = %s%n", a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
a=true, b=true = true
a=true, b=false = false
a=false, b=true = false
a=false, b=false = true
```

So the answer to your quiz question was *B. Only when the value of a is the same as the value of b.*

Comment: thanks for the help!
by the way, what are the [] for?

Comment: I get the answer now, but, I don't understand the code you wrote to prove it